# How do I programatically override the formatter of a Ruport data table?

Tags: ruby, ruport

I have a pretty straight-forward Ruport setup in my Rails app, where the Ruport controller is passed a `Report::Data::Table` instance:

```
class Reporter < Ruport::Controller
  stage :headline, :data, :footer
  required_option :report

def setup
    report_klass = options.report.report_model
    report_klass ||= Report
    self.data = report_klass.send(:report_table_by_sql, options.report.query)
  end
end
```

The `Data::Table` instance that is stored in data uses `Ruport::Data::Table` as its delegated controller when asked to render, so that's what gets called when I later call

```
output << data.to_html
```

How can I tell data to delegate its rendering methods to the Reporter class, so all my hook overrides can live in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruport's [API documentation](http://api.rubyreports.org/classes/Ruport/Formatter.html#M000174) makes it clear that you can register a single `Formatter` descendant with multiple `Controllers`, so if you want to have a single formatter that implements all the hooks, you can simply say as much:

```
class DualPurposeFormatter < Ruport::Formatter::HTML
  renders :html, :for => [Reporter, Ruport::Controller::Table]

  #for Reporter controller
  def build_headline
    #...
  end

  #for Ruport::Controller::Table
  def build_row(row_data)
    #...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruport formatters are designed to be encapsulated in a separate class that inherits from Formatter.
I believe something similar to this will achieve what you want:

```
# Inherits all the default build methods from the HTML Formatter
class ReporterTableHTMLFormatter < Ruport::Formatter::HTML
  # Sets this class to render Ruport Tables
  # (Data instead of Controller may also work, the code path is a bit unclear/overloaded)
  renders :html, :for => Ruport::Controller::Table

  # Build table row
  def build_row(data)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I knew this already, but the missing piece in my head was that you can register formatters for more than one controller… Thanks!